# Auditing Microservices

Tags: java, web-services, microservices

I have list of microservices I am calling multiple services from same controller.
I want to track the change of the object state before and after service.

How the design should be or there any standards to audit microservices?

Thanks Vijay

Comment: I will suggest you to use Proxy pattern and cache the calls. This will reduce network round trips. 

As you asked about best practices, refer specification for fully RESTFul service standard and Richardson Maturity Model

Comment: This should be useful: https://danpalmer.me/blog/your-api-is-not-restful

Comment: Tracing may help you, for example using jaeger.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this at the application level. You can use the AOP frameworks for Java(eg Spring AOP or/and AspectJ) to intercept the data in/out of your microservices endpoints or your regular methods. The `@Around` annotation allows you to intercept the incoming data(method parameters/arguments) and the outgoing data(return values/responses).

```
@Aspect
public class AuditAspect {

   @Around("execution(* com.foobar.controllers.*.*(..))") 
   public void doAudit(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()); //get method name
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs())); //get the arguments/params

    joinPoint.proceed(); //continue 

    System.out.println("intercept response ");

   }

}
```